# measure center width of Trapezoid OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I am trying to measure center width (w3) of the following trapezoid without success.
Is there anyway I can measure this?

at the moment I can measure the center point and print the each contour points.

here is my code:

```
 Mat gray;
    cvtColor(inputImage, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    cv::findContours(gray, contours, hierarchy, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    vector<Moments>mu(contours.size());
    for(int i=0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        mu[i] = moments(contours[i],false);
    }


    vector<Point2f>mc(contours.size());
    for(int i=0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        mc[i] = Point2f(mu[i].m10/mu[i].m00, mu[i].m01/mu[i].m00);
        //cout << mu[i].m01/mu[i].m00 <<endl;
        for(size_t cP=0; cP < contours[i].size(); cP++)
            {
                cv::Point currentContourPixel = contours[i][cP];

                //cout <<currentContourPixel<<endl;
            }

    }
```

[trapezoid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoCu0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using elementary math functions.

1. Properly prepare the image (colospace conversions, threshold ...) and search for contours then select the one that is the trapezoid.
2. Calclate the higest and lowest point.
3. Make 4 lists for every side (a, b, c, d) of the trapezoid and one for temporary (b+d)
4. Iterate through contour and append to a, c and temporary b+d. Points in a should have the same y axis as the lowest point y axis. Points in c should have the same y axis as the highest point y axis. Points in b+d should have all other points.
5. Sort a and c by their x axis - smallest to biggest.
6. Itterate through b+d and append b and d. Points in d should have the same or smaller x axis as the first element in c. Points in b should have the same or bigger x axis as the last element in c.
7. Calculate the middle points for all sides. Formula for the middle point of each side `X,Y = ((x2+x1)/2, (y2+y1)/2)`
8. Your width equals to distance between middle point of d to middle point of b. Formula for distance between two points `sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)`.

I have made an example in Python (I don't know the C++ syntax) but it should be easy to translate to C++. Hope it helps a bit. Cheers!

Example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read the image
img = cv2.imread('trapez.png')

# Transform to gray colorspace and invert Otsu threshold the image
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,0,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

# Search for contours and select the biggest
_, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cnt = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# Calclate the higest and lowest point
top = tuple(cnt[cnt[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
bottom = tuple(cnt[cnt[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])

# Make 4 lists for every side of trapezoid and one for temporary bd
a = []
b = []
c = []
d = []
bd_temp = []

# Iterate through contour and append to a, c and temporary list
## Points in a should have the same y axis as the lowest point y axis
## Points in c should have the same y axis as the highest point y axis
## Temporary should have all others (b and d)
for i in cnt:
    if i[0][1] == top[1]:
        c.append(tuple(i[0]))
    if i[0][1] == bottom[1]:
        a.append(tuple(i[0]))
    else:
        bd_temp.append(tuple(i[0]))

# Sort a and c by their x axis - smallest to biggest
a.sort(key = lambda x: x[0])
c.sort(key = lambda x: x[0])

# Itterate through bd_temp and append b and d
## Points in d should have the same or smaller x axis as the first element in c
## Points in b should have the same or bigger x axis as the last element in c
for i in bd_temp:
    if i[0] <= c[0][0]:
        d.append(i)        
    if i[0] >= c[-1][0]:
        b.append(i)

# Sort b and d by their x axis - smallest to biggest
b.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])
d.sort(key = lambda x: x[1])

# Calculate middle points for all sides ((x2+x1)/2, (y2+y1)/2)
half_line_a = tuple([int((a[0][0]+a[-1][0])/2), int((a[0][1]+a[-1][1])/2)])
half_line_c = tuple([int((c[0][0]+c[-1][0])/2), int((c[0][1]+c[-1][1])/2)])
half_line_b = tuple([int((b[0][0]+b[-1][0])/2), int((b[0][1]+b[-1][1])/2)])
half_line_d = tuple([int((d[0][0]+d[-1][0])/2), int((d[0][1]+d[-1][1])/2)])

# Optional integers for calculating the width
x2 = half_line_b[0]
x1 = half_line_d[0]
y2 = half_line_b[1]
y1 = half_line_d[1]

# Width equals to distance between middle point of d to middle point of b
## Formula for distance between two points sqrt((x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2)
width = np.sqrt(((x2-x1)**2)+((y2-y2)**2))
center = tuple([half_line_c[0], y1])

# Optional drawing on the image
cv2.arrowedLine(img, half_line_b, half_line_d, (0,0,255), 1)
cv2.arrowedLine(img, half_line_d, half_line_b, (0,0,255), 1)
cv2.circle(img, center, 2, (255,0,0), -1)
cv2.putText(img,'Width = '+str(width),(20,20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5,(0,0,0),1,cv2.LINE_AA)

# Display the image
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Result:

[image]